# SwiftUI Add Checkmark to Textfields if Passwords Match

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am putting the final touches on the authentication portion of an app I'm building and trying to have a checkmark appear on my password textfields if the passwords match.

The first block of code is from my view that allows users to sign up. I'm trying to call a function in a different file that contains the SecureInputView.

The function checkpasswordsMatch returns the correct value of true or false but it doesn't seem to update the SecureInputView. I think I'm pretty close and probably have an error in using the property wrappers. Cannot seem to figure it out. I'm newer to SwiftUI. Any help would be appreciated.

1. Code from Sign Up View

```
import SwiftUI
import SCLAlertView
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseAnalyticsSwift

@MainActor
final class SignUpEmailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    //INITIALIZE VARIABLES
    @Published var email: String = ""
    @Published var newPassword: String = ""
    @Published var newPasswordConfirm: String = ""
    @Published var passwordsMatch: Bool = false
    
    func signUp() async throws {
        //CONFIRM EMAIL FIELD IS NOT BLANK
        guard !email.isEmpty else {
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "Please enter a valid email")
            return
        }
        //CONFIRM PASSWORD FIELDS ARE NOT BLANK
        guard !newPassword.isEmpty else {
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "Please enter a valid password") // Error
            return
        }
        guard !newPasswordConfirm.isEmpty else {
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "Please enter a valid password") // Error
            return
        }
        // RUN THE SIGN UP FUNCTION
        let returnedUserData = try await AuthenticationManager.shared.createUser(email: email, password: newPasswordConfirm)
        SCLAlertView().showSuccess("Success", subTitle: "Your account has been created. Welcome!")
        print(returnedUserData)

    }
    
    func checkPasswordsMatch(password1: String, password2: String) -> Bool {
        if password1 == password2 && password1 != "" && password2 != "" {
            print("Match")
            return true
        }
        else {
            print("NO MATCH")
            return false
        }
    }
}

struct SignUpEmailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = SignUpEmailViewModel()
    @Binding var showSignInView: Bool
    @State var agreeToTerms: Bool = false
    
    //MAIN BODY OF THE VIEW
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            //APP LOGO
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "logo_color_nobackground.png")!)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .padding()
            
            //EMAIL FIELD
            TextField("Choose Email", text: $viewModel.email)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
            //PASSWORD FIELD 1
            SecureInputView("Choose Password", text: $viewModel.newPassword, passwordsMatch: viewModel.checkPasswordsMatch(password1: viewModel.newPassword, password2: viewModel.newPasswordConfirm), isSingleField: false)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .textContentType(.newPassword)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
            
            //PASSWORD FIELD 2
            SecureInputView("Re-enter Password", text: $viewModel.newPasswordConfirm, passwordsMatch: viewModel.checkPasswordsMatch(password1: viewModel.newPassword, password2: viewModel.newPasswordConfirm), isSingleField: false)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .textContentType(.newPassword)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            
            //TOS AND PRIVACY POLICY BUTTON
            HStack {
                if agreeToTerms == true {
                    Button {
                        agreeToTerms = false
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "checkmark.square.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    
                }
                if agreeToTerms == false {
                    Button {
                        agreeToTerms = true
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "square")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                Text("I agree to the Terms of Service and Privacy Policy")
                    .font(.caption)
            }
            .padding([.top])
            
            //SIGN UP BUTTON
            Button {
                Task {
                    do {
                        if viewModel.newPassword == viewModel.newPasswordConfirm {
                            try await viewModel.signUp()
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(viewModel.email, forKey: "defaultEmail")
                            showSignInView = false
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            SCLAlertView().showError("Sign Up Error", subTitle: "Passwords must match. Please double check to ensure they do.") // Error
                        }
                    } catch {
                        if let error = error as NSError? {
                            firebaseErrorHandler(error: error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(height: 55)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(agreeToTerms ? Color.blue : Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding()
            }
            .disabled(agreeToTerms == false)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct SignUpEmailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignUpEmailView(showSignInView: .constant(false))
    }
}
```

2. Code from my utilities page that contains SecureInputView

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import SCLAlertView
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseAnalyticsSwift

final class Utilities {
    
    static let shared = Utilities()
    private init() {}
    
    @MainActor
    func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
        
        let controller = controller ??  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
    
}

//STRUCT TO BE ABLE TO VIEW THE SECUREFIELDS
struct SecureInputView: View {
 
    @Binding private var text: String
    @State private var passwordsMatch: Bool = true
    @State private var isSecured: Bool = true
    private var isSingleField: Bool
    
    private var title: String
    
    init(_ title: String, text: Binding<String>, passwordsMatch: Bool, isSingleField: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self._text = text
        self.passwordsMatch = passwordsMatch
        self.isSingleField = isSingleField
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            Group {
                if isSecured {
                    SecureField(title, text: $text)
                } else {
                    TextField(title, text: $text)
                }
            }
    
            HStack {
                if isSingleField == false && passwordsMatch == true {
                    Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation (.easeIn(duration: 0.2)) {
                        isSecured.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: self.isSecured ? "eye.slash" : "eye")
                        .accentColor(.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a `@Published` property. You can just use a computed property `var passwordsMatch: Bool { newPassword == newPasswordConfirm }`. You also shouldn't be using `@State` on `passwordsMatch ` inside `SecureInputView` -- that'll guarantee it won't update unless mutated from within the `View`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `passwordsMatch` can be a computed property and don't need to be `@Published`:

```
var passwordsMatch: Bool { newPassword == newPasswordConfirm }
```

Then, you shouldn't annotate `passwordsMatch` with `@State` inside `SecureInputView` -- by doing that, it won't get updated with new values from the parent component.